# Dagger 2 multiple Injection on Android

Tags: android, dagger

I have an Activity with 2 injections. Each injected component works alone, but injecting both leads to the following errors :

```
Error:(12, 10) error: android.app.Fragment cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
fr.daggertest.MainActivity.fragmentB
[injected field of type: android.app.Fragment fragmentB]

Error:(12, 10) error: android.app.Application cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
fr.daggertest.MainActivity.applicationA
[injected field of type: android.app.Application applicationA]
```

But they both are already @Provides annotated, so I don't see what's wrong ?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Inject
Fragment fragmentB;

@Inject
Application applicationA;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // create component & inject...
}
```

Modules & components :

```
@Component(modules={ModuleA.class})
@Singleton
public interface ComponentA {
    void inject(MainActivity activity);
}

@Component(modules={ModuleB.class})
@Singleton
public interface ComponentB {
    void inject(MainActivity activity);
}

@Module
public class ModuleA {
    Application mApplication;

    public ModuleA(Application application) {
        mApplication = application;
    }

    @Provides
    public Application provideApplication() {
        return mApplication;
    }
}

@Module
public class ModuleB {
     Fragment mFragment;

    public ModuleB(Fragment fragment) {
        mFragment = fragment;
    }

    @Provides
    public Fragment provideFragment() {
        return mFragment;
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't supply a method that provides `Activity`, only `Fragment` and `Application`. Also could you post your "create component & inject" code?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo, I edited the code. The "create component & inject" code is commented out, that's not the cause of the compile error.

Comment: Actually, it could. Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you try to inject an `Activity` with a `Component` Dagger 2 will check that `Component` can provide every dependency annotated with `@Inject`

Right now your `Components` (probably) only provides one of two dependencies. Make one component depend on the other one or make one of them take both `Modules`

Another possible solution could be change your `Component`s to this:

```
@Singleton
public interface ComponentA {
    Application getApplication();
}

@Component(modules={ModuleB.class})
@Singleton
public interface ComponentB {
    Fragment getFragment();
}
```

and change your injecting code to this:

```
ComponentA componentA = ...
ComponentB componentB = ...
applicationA = componentA.getApplication();
fragmentB = componentB.getFragment();
```

Comment: I can't make one depend on the other because they both already depends on another component with different scope (not shown in the example for simplicity). Make one of them take both module seems wrong as they are totally unrelated.

Comment: In that case you'll probably need to inject your fields "manually". Check my edit